# socket programming in C to make connection unknown to server

Tags: c, sockets

I've just completed with client server programming.
The Client-Server program is running and server replies correctly that it has received the bytes.

Now I want to do it in a way so that I don't need to run "server" program.
I just want client program to run and entering the ip i.e. 127.0.0.1 on same machine...it should connect. It should connect properly to perform operations like send the bytes/fine to server etc

Is this possible, plz help. (in this sense SERVER PROGRAMMING IS NOT NEEDED).
I just want client program to run and connect to server and send data to remote pc.

Comment: Would you like one program to act as both client and server?

Comment: What do you mean? A connected socket always has two endpoints and to connect there needs to be a "server" "program" that listens to a port. The server program can run on an arbitrary machine, as long as the address and port are known to the client.

Comment: what i exactly want is that, I'm just entering the IP address of another PC and connecting to it by using client programming in C. I only want to do coding on client side. Assuming that the port number I used for remote PC is open.

Comment: @rahulkapoor, So you don't want to enter the IP every time?

Comment: No, I want to enter the IP everytime..like "$pr1 ipaddress" ans port 8080 in my code. I don't want the server to interfere in it. I don't want that "sending request", "request accepted", "sending data", "data recieved".... I just don't want server to know i.e disabling "request accepted" and "data received"

Comment: I am not getting your requirement you want to connect to some other PC or want to loop back?
If you want to connect to some other PC then you have to make a server in that PC which accepts connection request of your client

Comment: @rahulkapoor, What are "sending request", "request accepted", etc.? Are they messages sent from the client?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible.

You can't have client/server without the server, you can't "just connect" if there's nothing to connect to.

That a particular IP address and port is "open" *means* that there is some service running on that host, which is listening to the port.

Comment: ok, But if I mention the IP address of that system and the correct port number say, 8080...even then it is not possible ??

Comment: @rahulkapoor If you're trying to connect to a system on a specific port, something **must** be running on that system and listening to that specific port. And the thing that is listening **is** the server.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible you have to write separately one client program as well as one server program and you can use this loop back ip but then also you need to write two programs

Comment: No, I want to enter the IP everytime..like "$pr1 ipaddress" ans port 8080 in my code. I don't want the server to interfere in it. I don't want that "sending request", "request accepted", "sending data", "data recieved".... I just don't want server to know i.e disabling "request accepted" and "data received"

Comment: @unmang2203 note that the client and server don't have to be in separate programs, **they could be parts of the same program**.

Comment: in your post you said that you don't want to run server program then it is not possible.... in client/server programming you have to run both the programs. if it isa on the same machine then also you must need to run them both..client can't perform this task by it own.

Comment: @zakinster Ya then it could be possible but then also you need to use fork or thread cause you need to run this both process concurrently...

Comment: using fork method and what is this about that "connect using POST method", I knwo what is POST server..but how to use this in code

Comment: POST method is using http header so need to read a bit about it for its programming here is a little example of that POST method

Comment: i post it as answer as it is too long for comment

Answer (score 0):

A socket connection always requires one endpoint to act as a client and one to act as a server.

But what you can do is have an application which acts both as a client and as a server by opening both a client- and a server socket.

Answer (score 0):

POST method is using http header so need to read a bit about it for its programming here is a little example of that POST method

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 #include<stdlib.h>

 #include<usr/mynetwork.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int sockfd, n;
char buff[MAXLINE],recvline[MAXLINE];
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

if(argc != 3){
    printf("usage: httppostconnect <ipaddress> <relative_url>");
    exit(0);
}

if( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1 ){
    printf("socket: error");
    exit(0);
}

bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(80);  //connect to http server

if(inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&servaddr.sin_addr) < 0){
    printf("port: assigned invalid");
    exit(0);
}
if( connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr)) == -1){
    printf("connect: error");
    exit(0);
}

//Sending Http header
bzero(&buff,sizeof(buff));

char postdata[] = "param1=value1&param2=value";  /* Change param and value here */

sprintf(buff,"POST %s HTTP1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nReferer: <REFERER HERE>\r\nAccept-Language: en-us\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n%s",argv[2],strlen(postdata),postdata);

if(write(sockfd,buff,strlen(buff)+1) == -1)
    err_exit("write");

while ((n =read(sockfd,recvline,sizeof(recvline))) > 0){
    recvline[n] = 0;
    if(fputs(recvline,stdout) == EOF)
        err_abort("read error");            
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: file mynetwork is not any special i just included socket files and other header files in that

Comment: Your best bet is to read the HTTP rfc to see how to properly form a POST request.
Once you understand the protocol properly you can then write it in C code.